# Is private or public matters in java?

Tags: java

Recently a student introduce me AOP in java, he said that

"If you make use of the frameworks provided by java, you don't need to care about the low level design problems like "this data, methods should be private or public" again, many things are generated and determined for you by the java EE frameworks, you only need to care about the business logic. private or public is a stupid, unimportant, low quality question, because when you using the framework, you stand on a higher level abstraction to solve the problem and should not care those details.Only those low level java programmers would care about private or public".

I tried to study AOP and java framework(not an expert of java) but I never get the idea why "private or public is a stupid question if you use java framework"

My question is :
How could the AOP and java framework make the basic concepts become unimportant and obsolete?What kind of magic they apply?

Comment: Your "colleague" (and you edited to 'student' just to conceal his identity?) probably doesn't learn enough of objects orientated programming nor learnt how to write smooth and neat codes. I bet he doesn't knows how to do polymorphism nor inheritiance. Which makes him incapability to writing any legitimate classes. Yes, you still could do a simple business logic, but when your business logics gets more and more complicated and more features, you code will be extremely hard and expensive to maintain. You might ends up getting extremely buggy codes when your codebase grows.

Comment: Based on your "colleague" logics, he should instead say all the codes could be written under one public static void main method and his business logic will run too. He will end up getting messy unreadable codes and takes longer time when there's a logic change or when he's debugging his app. There is a reason why people write objects and giving the proper access modifier rights.

Comment: Ah ... where would we be without the wisdom of youth? :-) :-)  Hint: you should pay more attention to your lecturers than your fellow students.

Answer (score 3):

No magic, its lies, public and private are really important

They are the basis of code, 
The programmer's solemn obligation is to MAINTAIN THE INTEGRITY OF THE OBJECT